# installing Basemap module - Command ''python setup.py egg_info'' failed with error code 1

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, matplotlib-basemap

I have run into a problem that has been bothering me for hours. I found multiple occurrences of this problem (some are kinda old) in this site and others but no solution worked for me so I decided to try and ask for help on my individual problem..

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 35-32, 32 bit. I have downloaded basemap-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and tried to install it with `pip install [FULL PATH]` in Administrator Command Prompt. I have installed a few packages successfully from the same site this way, yet this one brings up this error:

```
> C:\Users\Chris>pip install
> C:\Users\Chris\Downloads\PythonWindowsModules\basemap-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
> Processing
> c:\users\chris\downloads\pythonwindowsmodules\basemap-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
> Collecting pyproj>=1.9.3 (from basemap==1.1.0)   Using cached
> pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
>     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>     using bundled proj4..
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
> line 477, in __init__
>         self.vc_ver = self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
>     IndexError: list index out of range
> 
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>       File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-prn63hc6\pyproj\setup.py",
> line 72, in <module>
>         objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py",
> line 317, in compile
>         self.initialize()
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py",
> line 210, in initialize
>         vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
> line 172, in msvc14_get_vc_env
>         return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
> line 771, in __init__
>         self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
>       File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py",
> line 480, in __init__
>         raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
>     distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
> http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
> 
>     ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-prn63hc6\pyproj\
```

I have tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, `easy_install -U setuptools`, `pip install --upgrade pip`, `pip install ez_setup`. All of the updates/requirements are shown to be up to date/already satisfied.

I do have matplotlib and numpy and they are working fine. According to `pip -V`, I have a pip version of 9.0.1 (Python 3.5). Are there any suggestions or anyone knowing what is going on? I can provide more information/tests if required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your error says , `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
> http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools` have you tried installing visual C++?

Comment: Install [pyproj](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) before basemap.

Comment: I have visual C++, I checked so in the Control Panel. But what I did not have was actually pyproj >.>  I pip installed that and then basemap installed fine.. Thank you cgohlk, and Anil_M for your suggestion! This is now fixed for me.

Comment: @cgohlke please post your comment as an answer so others can find it!