# Unable to install basemap package in python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm a newbie and so have problems installing the **basemap** package. I have **Python 3.6.0**(32 bit, windows) 
I want to install basemap package.(Numpy and Matplotlib have already been installed). Versions available on internet are 3.3 compatible. Things I've tried:

1. Installing it with pip. Didn't work.
2. Found another package http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap compatible. When tried to install, it gave egg info code 1 error.
3. Created virtual env and tried installing it. Gives error

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What error does it output?

Comment: what is the result of using pip? that would be the easiest route to install. Trying updating pip if necessary.

Comment: Install [pyproj](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj) before basemap

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42825511

Comment: @cgohlke While installing pyproject I get the error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:Users\welcom\Local\Temp\pip-build-pnior3\pyproj\          I don't understand this error.

Comment: Problem solved :) Thank you, everyone. I was trying to execute .whl file in windows without going into the right directory which gave me the egginfo_error. @cgohlke Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just wanted to add for anyone having this problem that @cgohlke 's suggestion of install pyproj first resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

the egg error is because GEOS is missing

try direct to install a wheel package:
get it from:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

then install with (case python 3.7 win64):

```
  py -m pip install "C:\maxbook\maxboxpython\basemap-1.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
```